# Lato Hairline Light doesn't render in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

But it does in chrome!
CSS:

```
h3
        {
            font-family: 'Lato Hairline Light';
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            opacity: 0;
            color: lime;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-name: fadeIn;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-delay: 1s;
        }
```

Renders just fine in Chrome:
[image]

But renders as the default font in Firefox:
[image]

This only happens with the "Light" version of Lato Hairline. If I just use "Lato" or "Lato Hairline", it renders fine in both browsers.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
EDIT: Added

```
@font-face {
             font-family: 'Lato Hairline';
             src: url('LATO-HAIRLINE.TTF') format('truetype');
         }
```

EDIT2: "Lato Hairline" with font-weight set to normal is not the same as "Lato Hairline Light".
Here's "Lato Hairline Light" + Bold:
[image]

Here's "Lato Hairline" + Bold:
[image]

Here's "Lato Hairline" normal:
[image]

Here's "Lato" + Light:
[image]

The first one is the one that is displayed in chrome and the one I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because since it's an H3, firefox is applying an artificial «Bold effect» and since it cannot render it properly, it probably messes up the font. Are you loading the font from Google Font? If so, it's often better to use the font weight associated with it. If you are using fontface with the font downloaded on your own server, you should create only 1 font-family and create font-weight values that are relative to your font. i.e

```
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'DroidSerif';
      src: url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
   }
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'DroidSerif';
     src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: italic;
  }
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'DroidSerif';
     src: url('DroidSerif-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: normal;
 }
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerif';
    src: url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
 }
```

From the tutorial: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/

It's easier and safer then with the browser. Often, chrome is understanding more thing then it should and firefox is bringing you the reality back in your face eheh

If it is fontface, could you show us how you include them to your website? It could also be a problem with the file not being accepted by Firefox

If it's a google font, do it that way:

add this in your `head` section

```
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then, you just have to do this:

```
    .lato-thin{
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
     }
```

Look at this page to have more info: https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse

Here is a JS fiddle, the javascript in the fiddle does the same thing as pasting the link in your CSS. Tested it on firefox and it works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/3db60oh7/

Comment: I didn't include any font faces. Also bold "Lato Hairline" != "Lato Hairline Light".

Comment: Okay, did you used Google Font then? Because it is not a font websafe font

Comment: I put in "font-weight: normal" to avoid the artificial bold effect but that's not the problem. I just seems that firefox can't find the font.

Comment: Yea I included the Lato family.

Comment: Added a fiddle also so you can test it on firefox

Comment: hmm if you try font-weight 300 it'll be "lato light" maybe it's what you need?

Comment: Edited question and included it. It's not the same. "Lato" in general is an entirely different font family than "Lato Hairline".

Comment: Ohh I see, because I know that this is the free lato font for web from Google and when you download it, it contains a "Hairline" but the equivalent for the Web is Thin... Try to inspect element in firefox and see if it loads the font properly